Read defaultValue programmatically in React Hook Form
I have two Select boxes that represent a key value pair. The selected Key value filters the Values options when onChange is called. This works fine for new items, but when I load in an object, the Values Select box doesn't load any options because it is empty until a Key has been selected and defaultValue doesn't trigger onChange. Is there a way to read the defaultValue, perhaps in a useEffect block to mimic the onChange event and populate the Values options?
//questionToEdit represents a potential object being passed in to be edited
const Question = ({questionToEdit}) => {
  const methods = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      conditions: questionToEdit.conditions || [{ key: "", comparator: "", value: "" }],
    }
  });
};

//The component is rendered in a useFieldArray block as follows:
{conditionFields.map((field, index) => (
  <Condition key={field.id} index={index} vals={conditionValues}/>
))}

//On the rendered component, selectables is a useState driven element
const [selectables, setSelectables] = useState([]);

//This Array is populated by the values of the key when the key is selected
onChange={val => {filterSelectablesOnClick(val.value)}}

const filterSelectablesOnClick = (values) => {
    var newState = values.map((item) => {
        return { label: item, value: item };
    });
    setSelectables(newState);
};

If I could get the defaultValue being passed in to the Key Select component in a useEffect block, I could grab the string[] value and pass it into the filterSelectables method but I cannot find a way to do this. Any solutions?
